# Query through JSON Array with multiple values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

**MySQL version: 5.7.29**

I've a column `layout_status` with JSON datatype which contains array of values such as:

```js
["Layouted"]
["Retired"]
["Verified"]
["Layouted", "Retired"]
["Layouted", "Verified"]
```

I want to select the records containing either "Layouted" or "Retired" or both.

I thought performing **IN** like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE layout_status IN ('[\"Layouted\",\"Retired\"]');` would solve problem but it returns zero results.

Later I've tried with **JSON_CONTAINS** like below

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users
  WHERE ( JSON_CONTAINS(layout_status, "[\"Layouted\"]")
  OR      JSON_CONTAINS(layout_status, "[\"Retired\"]")
        )
```

But with the above query I get the records that has only either "Layouted" or "Retired". Records with ["Layouted", "Retired"] are ignored.

Is there any way to get all the records that contains "Layouted" or "Retired" or both?

Comment: Dquote chars are string-typed value delimiters, not a part of a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) properly. You want to search for a string inside an array, not an array inside an array:

```sql
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(layout_status, '"Layouted"')
OR    JSON_CONTAINS(layout_status, '"Retired"')
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac6bd0ad3f4c293741cf3f6bd5b68576)

Comment: When I use this I get an error Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0.